# The meaning of the function $f(x) = \operatorname{dist} (x, \mathbb N) $

Tags: real-analysis

That would be a simple question but I am having a hard time understanding the distribution function.

Suppose $f(x) = \operatorname{dist} (x, \mathbb N) $, then what does it mean? Does that function $f(x)$ is continuous at point $x$ but not at natural number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $\operatorname{dist}$ stands for *distance*, not distribution.

The distance from $x$ to $\mathbb N$ is $\inf\{x-n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Which in practical terms means: the absolute value of the difference between $x$ and the nearest integer.

[image]

This function is continuous everywhere, but is not differentiable at the integers and half-integers. As such, it is used as the basis of the construction of some [nowhere differentiable functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!